# Selenium Error: UnsupportedCommandException

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

> I'm getting following error while executing my code using Selenium Webdriver:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/0c0ee24f-ebbe-4a28-97f6-8339b9778bf8/moveto did not match a known command
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
```

Help to resolve above error.

Comment: Add your code, what you have tried, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this error because of the selenium version.
i have used 3.0.1 and once i downgraded it , UnsupportedCommandException problem was resolved.

Comment: Since you've solved your own problem, could you please mark your question as answered so others know this is a possible solution to the problem you had.